# Unittest example from doc raises AttributeError

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I'm new to unittesting in python. I tried the unittest example from the documentation:

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = list(range(10))

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, list(range(10)))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running this code gives me following error on the commandline:

```
D:\src>python foo.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
  class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestCase'
```

I'm using ActiveState Python 3.2. Why do I get an attribute error here?

Comment: Do you have a dir named `unittest` in `d:\src\` ?

Comment: to debug, add a print(unittest) statement to your code and see if it is the stdlib's unittest module or your own file instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you have a second `unittest` module or package in your python path.

If you created a `unittest.py` file or a `unittest` directory containing an `__init__.py` file, python could find that before it finds the normal module in the standard python library.

Naming a local module or package `unittest` is the equivalent of naming a local variable `list` or `dict` or `map`; you are masking the built-in name with a local redefinition.

Rename that module or package to something else to fix this.

Comment: Yes, a directory. Thanks for answer.